# Not able to open spinnaker deck UI using machine ip address on EC2

Tags: spinnaker

I have successfully installed spinnaker on ec2 from an already provided community image and have been able to access all the services using ip apart from deck (ui gateway). For all other services, I have changed the yml to bind to the ip address and I have changed the `port.conf` in apache to Listen 9000(all traffic). I could not find any yml for Deck separately in spinnaker config.

Additionally, in my ec2 settings for security group I have also opened up to allow inbound connections to port 9000.

As mentioned I can access all other services using ip except Deck. Deck is still binding itself to `localhost:9000`.

It will be very helpful if someone can point any steps I am missing here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you restart apache (`sudo service apache2 restart`)?

And are you able to `curl your-ip:9000` directly on the vm?

I just performed the following steps:

- Build a vm from scratch and install spinnaker via the curl command here (http://spinnaker.io/documentation/getting_started.html).
- Confirm `curl localhost:9000` succeeds and `curl my-ip:9000` fails.
- `sudo vi /etc/apache2/ports.conf`
- Edit the Listen statement in that file as per (http://spinnaker.io/documentation/troubleshooting.html#why-cant-i-access-spinnaker-using-my-machines-ip-addr-or-hostname)
- Restart apache via `sudo service apache2 restart`
- Confirm `curl my-ip:9000` works.
- Specify ingress rules to allow external traffic to reach this vm on :9000.

Thanks,
-Matt

Comment: Thanks a ton Matt. Worked like a charm.My bad i forgot to restart the apache service.That was the step I missed.

Comment: The troubleshoot page returned 404 for me. This link has a script that helped me: https://blog.spinnaker.io/exposing-spinnaker-to-end-users-4808bc936698